# SCSS and BEM in Shopify

Tags: css, sass, shopify, bem

I am writing a Shopify theme and want to use BEM and SCSS for all styling in a Shopify theme.  For some reason the elements inside my block aren't being changed along with my style rules.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="featured-hero">
    <a href="/go/to-here">
        <div class="featured-hero__hero-img"></div>
        <div class="featured-hero__text">
            Awesome text here
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

It will contain an image with text over it.  Simple enough!  Here's the SCSS

```
.featured-hero {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: firebrick;

    &[class*='__text'] {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
 }
```

The style rules inside the parent block are acting as expected but everything inside the `&[class*='__text']` block isn't doing anything.  Why is this not being rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: ugly sccs there, you don't need use ```&[class*='__text']``` just ```&__text```

Comment: @LeandroRuel I believe there are constraints around what I can do here- Shopify supports Sass 3.2 and I believe this syntax became available in Sass 3.3.  Your suggestion caused the compiler to fail- I already tried

Comment: this is not possible, i do it in all my projects always with the lastest version of sass

Comment: @LeandroRuel in shopify?

Comment: even if it is shopify look: https://jsfiddle.net/guedefqf/

Comment: @LeandroRuel thank you for you help but this syntax is supported in Sass **3.3**. Shopify supports Sass **3.2** which does not allow this syntax yet.

Comment: really? so the solution is nest all the child classes  ```.featured-hero { .featured-hero__text {} }```

Answer (score 1):

There is no element that has a `featured-hero` class that also has a class that contains the string `__text`.

The selector should be

```
&__text
```